# Why is my Maps object undefined in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is my code: I just want to retrieve the Lat and lng from the output. but I keep getting an error that "Maps" is not defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var address = "200 South Michigan, Chicago, IL";
        // Gets the geographic coordinates for Chicago.
        var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            var result = response.results[i];

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is `Maps` defined? (it isn't in the posted code and isn't part of the google maps javascript API v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is called `Geocoder` not `newGeocoder` and it's available on the `google.maps` object not `Maps`. You need to create a new instance using the `new` keyword. After that you can call method `geocode` on your instance:

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 geocoder.geocode(address);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting an error on this piece of the code "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"

Comment: That's not a piece of code, it's the URL that's supposed to be the value of the `src` attribute of the `script` tag, just like you've got in the code like you've posted in your question and it's ok, produces no errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion. If you're using it client side (JS), use `new google.maps.Geocoder()`. However if you're using it server side (googlescript .gs file), you have to use the `Maps` object as you originally mentioned.

Client side docs: [geocode-JS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Server side docs: [apps-script geodecoder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder)